# How do I return a value from the Function used to initialize an array in Mathematica

Tags: function, math, wolfram-mathematica

In this example I'm trying to create an Array of length 5 where each ellement contains the number of times .3 can be summed without exceeding 1. i.e. 3 times. So each element should contain the number 3. Here is my code:

```
Array[(
  workingCount = 0; 
  workingSum = 0; 
  done = false; 
  While[! done, 
   workingSum = workingSum + .3; 
   If[workingSum > 1, done = true; workingCount, workingCount++]
  ])
  , 5]
```

In the 3rd to last line there I have `workingCount` without a `;` after it because it seems like in Mathematica omitting the `;` causes the value a statement resolves to to be returned.

Instead I get this:

```
{Null[1], Null[2], Null[3], Null[4], Null[5]}
```

Why does this happen? How can I get my program to do what I want it to do? i.e. In the context of the function passed to Array to initialize it's elements, how to I use complicated multi-line functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, one way to be able to do that in Mathematica  is

```
Array[
 Catch[
   workingCount = 0;
   workingSum = 0;
   done = False;
   While[! done,
    workingSum = workingSum + .3;
    If[workingSum > 1,
     done = True; Throw@workingCount,
     workingCount++]]] &,
 5]
```

Second, and most important: you  never should do that in Mathematica!  Really.

Please visit for example the [Stack Exchange site for Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com), and read the questions an answers there to get some grip on the programming style.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are trying to initialize your array, but are trying to do so without an explicit function call - which is what you need to do.

See here for documentation on Arrays in Mathematica:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Array.html

That aside, and minor errors (True and False have to be capitalized), this is what you want to do:

```
f[x_] :=
  (
   workingCount = 0;
   workingSum = 0;
   done = False;

   While[done != True, workingSum = workingSum + 0.3; 
    If[workingSum > 1, done = True, workingCount++]
    ];
   Return[workingCount];
   );

Array[f, 5] (* The array here is generating 5 values of the return value of f[x_] *)
```

Comment: And, I forgot to mention, that in your case, you needed a return statement, which is why your Array is filled with Null values. Alternatively, instead of a named function like I showed you, you could use an anonymous function (the ampersand), as suggested by @belisarius.

Comment: Ah! I see what you're saying @belisarius. Good catch! Edited.